# hta using vbscript - paths and other text with spaces, represented as variables, in another line of code

Tags: variables, vbscript, quotes, spaces, hta

My registering here is a strong testimony to the excellent answers I've found here before.
I hope someone can help me with what feels like it should be a simple issue, if not, I fear for rapidly increasing baldness.

I've created an HTA file to perfom file operations, renaming, copying, adding on the date, etc.

My problem is that I have several variables who are set equal to file paths that include spaces. other variables are set to user input, which will include spaces. These variables are then used in other lines of code. But those other lines break when they encouter the space in the "extended" varable.

For examples, here is one line in particular driving me up the wall.

```
Sub makemp3
If mp3radio(0).Checked Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "cmd.exe /c " &lameexe& " " &defaultpathfile& " " &sermonmp3folder& "\" &newfile& ".mp3"
Else
End If
End Sub
```

In the above case, the variables are set at the beginning of the script block to...

```
lameexe="D:\LAME\lame3.99.5-libsndfile\lame.exe"
defaultpathfile = sermonflacfolder&"\"&defaultflac
sermonmp3folder = "D:\SermonMP3"
newfile = datebox.value&"_"& titlebox.value
```

The databox is poplulated by a sub...

```
'pouplate input boxes with variables as default text
'==============================================
sub Window_onload
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set ObjEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
  datebox.value = calcdate
end sub
```

calcdate, in turn is created by another sub...

```
'setup and perform date calculations
'======================================
days=DatePart("d", now)
monthdig=DatePart("m", now)
years=DatePart("yyyy", now)
amps=Hour(now)

If monthdig <10 Then months="0"&monthdig Else months=monthdig

If amps <15 Then apm="am" Else apm="pm"

calcdate = years&"_"&months&"_"&days&"_"&apm
```

titlebox is currently just user input... the expected input would be similar to

```
What are we here for
```

or

```
Rev Phillip Smith
```

In all the reading I've done online, there is something I'm just not understanding about escaping quotes, double quotes, and chr(34).

this page seems hopeful, but I couldn't make it work with the variables in my script.

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/browse_thread/thread/2ca422f55628ea5e

Also, this page was the most verbal on the subject, but still it didn't show about using variable which themselves have no spaces, but the string inside them do.

groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/browse_thread/thread/2ca422f55628ea5e

I'm all out of brain power... Please help.
Thanks,
David

```
<script language="VBScript">



'
'
'deleteoldreapertemp subroutine adapted from:
'http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.wsh/msg/14df6623fc552446
'
'
'explaination of variables...
'
'windowwidth... the desired width of the script window
'windowlength... the desired length of the script window
'sermonflacfolder... the desired location reaper renders the sermon file to
'defaultflac... this is the name used when the sermon file is rendered
'calcdate... uses date variables to create the default flac file name
'defaultpathfile... a shortcut to use intead of sermonflacfolder&"\"&defaultflac
'tempdir... where reaper stores its temp files
'killdate... files older than this value will be deleted from reaper temp directory

'Manually set variables
'=================================
windowwidth = 400
windowlength = 500
sermonflacfolder= "D:\SermonFLAC"
defaultflac="test.flac"
defaultpathfile = sermonflacfolder&"\"&defaultflac
tempdir = "D:\reaper temp dir"
sermonmp3folder = "D:\SermonMP3"
lameexe="D:\LAME\lame3.99.5-libsndfile\lame.exe"
killdaysold = 14

'setup and perform date calculations
'======================================
days=DatePart("d", now)
monthdig=DatePart("m", now)
years=DatePart("yyyy", now)
amps=Hour(now)

If monthdig <10 Then months="0"&monthdig Else months=monthdig

If amps <15 Then apm="am" Else apm="pm"

calcdate = years&"_"&months&"_"&days&"_"&apm

killdate = date() &" - "& killdaysold


'resize script window before it is drawn... avoids flicker
'==========================================
Sub resizewindow
    window.resizeTo windowwidth,windowlength
end Sub
resizewindow()



'position script window at center of screen
'============================================
sub centerwindow
    screenWidth = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailWidth
    screenHeight = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailHeight
    posLeft = (screenWidth - windowwidth) / 2
    posTop = (screenHeight - windowlength) / 2    
    'move to centerscreen
    window.moveTo posLeft, posTop
  end sub
centerwindow()



'pouplate input boxes with variables as default text
'==============================================
sub Window_onload
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set ObjEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
  datebox.value = calcdate
end sub





</script>


















<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="RENAMER"
     SCROLL="NO">
</head>






<body>
<body bgcolor=c0c0c0>

<!text boxes setup here>
<!=====================================================================>
<p>

Accept calculated date and service (am or pm)<br>
or input correct date and service<br>
(yyyy_mm_dd_am)<br>

<input type="text" name="datebox" onclick="datebox.value=''">




<p>
<br>
Input sermon title <br>
<input type="text" name="titlebox" onfocus="titlebox.value=''">
<input type="button" name="examplesbutton" value="Examples" onClick="examplesclick" style="float: right;">
<br>
<br>
Create archive MP3?
<br>
Yes<input type="radio" name="mp3Radio" value="1" checked="true">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
No<input type="radio" name="mp3Radio" value="2">
<p>
Shutdown computer when script finishes?
<br>
Yes<input type="radio" name="shutdownRadio" value="1" checked="true">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
No<input type="radio" name="shutdownRadio" value="2" >
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" name="settingsbutton" value="Settings" onClick="settingsclick" style="float: left;">
<input type="button" name="runbutton" value="Run Script" onClick="MASTERSUB" style="float: right;">
<p> 



</body>























<script language="VBScript">



'CHECKING "DOES DEFAULT SERMON FILE EXIST?"
'=========================================
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(defaultpathfile)) Then
Else 
Msgbox "Default sermon file not found at:" & vbnewline & sermonflacfolder & "\" & defaultflac & vbnewline & vbnewline & "Check settings in Reaper (File\Render menu)" & vbnewline & vbnewline &  "Click Ok to exit script"
exitscript()
End If








Sub MASTERSUB
    lastchance
    deleteoldreapertemp
    rename
    makemp3
    checkfornewflac
    checkfornewmp3
    deletedefaultflac
    shutdownsub
End Sub





'MASTERSUB runs all the contained sub subs
'=====================================================
'=====================================================
'=====================================================
dim shutdownverify
dim newfile
dim newflacfound
dim newmp3found



Sub Delay ( seconds )
    Dim wshShell
    Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    wshShell.Run "ping -n " & ( seconds + 1 ) & " 127.0.0.1", 0, True
    Set wshShell = Nothing
End Sub




'last chance to abort shutdown
'=====================================================
Sub lastchance
    If shutdownradio(0).Checked Then
        lastchanceanswer = _
            Msgbox("Computer will shutdown when script finishes", _
             vbYesNo, "Last chance to abort shutdown")
            If lastchanceanswer = vbYes Then
                shutdownverify = "yes"
            Else
                shutdownverify = "no"
            End If
    Else
    End If
End Sub





'attempt to rename defaultflac
'=======================================================
Sub rename
newfile = datebox.value&"_"& titlebox.value
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile defaultpathfile , sermonflacfolder&"\"&newfile&".flac"
End Sub




'encode an mp3 version of the defaultflac file (only if the "yes" mp3 radio button is checked)
'===============================================
Sub makemp3
    If mp3radio(0).Checked Then
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "cmd.exe /c " &lameexe& " " &defaultpathfile& " " &sermonmp3folder& "\" &newfile& ".mp3"
    Else
    End If
End Sub


'check if new flac is was created successfully
'===============================================
Sub checkfornewflac
Delay 10
Dim count
count = 1

    Do 
        If (fso.FileExists(sermonflacfolder&"\"&datebox.value&"_"&titlebox.value&".flac")) Then
            newflacfound = "yes"
            'msgbox "new flac file found flag set to "&newflacfound
            Exit Sub            
        Else
            count=count+1
                If count >4 Then
                    newflacfound = "no"
                    'msgbox "new flac not found, flag set to "&newflacfound
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                End If
            Delay 10
        End If
    Loop 
End Sub





'check if mp3 was created sucessfully
'===============================================
Sub checkfornewmp3
Dim count
count = 1
If mp3radio(0).Checked Then
    Do 
        If (fso.FileExists(sermonmp3folder&"\"  & newfile & ".mp3")) Then
            newmp3found = "yes"
            'msgbox "new mp3 file found flag set to "&newmp3found
            Exit Sub            
        Else
            count=count+1
                If count >4 Then
                    newmp3found = "no"
                    'msgbox "new mp3 not found, flag set to "&newmp3found
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                End If
            Delay 10
        End If
    Loop 
End If
End Sub






'Delete default file
'=============================================
Sub deletedefaultflac
Delay 90
    If newflacfound = "yes" Then
        If newmp3found = "yes" Then
            set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            objFSO.DeleteFile defaultpathfile
        Else
            set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            objFSO.MoveFile defaultpathfile , sermonflacfolder&"\"& "aaERROR" &newfile&".flac"
        End If
    Else
        set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        objFSO.MoveFile defaultpathfile , sermonflacfolder&"\"& "00000_ERROR_" &newfile&".flac"
    End If
End Sub









'Delete old reaper temp files
'===========================================
Sub deleteoldreapertemp
'msgbox "starting 1sub"
    arFiles = Array()
    set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

selectfiles path, killdate, arFiles, true

    nDeleted = 0
        for n = 0 to ubound(arFiles)
  '=================================================
  ' Files deleted via FSO methods do *NOT* go to the recycle bin!!!
  '=================================================
  on error resume next 'in case of 'in use' files...
  arFiles(n).delete true
  if err.number <> 0 then
    wscript.echo "Unable to delete: " & arFiles(n).path
  else
    nDeleted = nDeleted + 1
  end if
  on error goto 0
next

'msgbox nDeleted & " of " & ubound(arFiles)+1 _
'  & " eligible files were deleted"
'msgbox "end 1 sub"
End Sub




sub selectfiles(sPath,vKillDate,arFilesToKill,bIncludeSubFolders)
  set folder = fso.getfolder(tempdir)
  set files = folder.files

'msgbox "startng 2 sub"


  on error resume next

  for each file in files
    ' uses error trapping around access to the
    ' Date property just to be safe
    '
    dtlastmodified = null
    on error resume Next
    dtlastmodified = file.datelastmodified
    on error goto 0
        if not isnull(dtlastmodified) Then
            if dtlastmodified < vKillDate then
                count = ubound(arFilesToKill) + 1
                redim preserve arFilesToKill(count)
                set arFilesToKill(count) = file
            end if
        end if
next

  if bIncludeSubFolders then
    for each fldr in folder.subfolders
      SelectFiles fldr.path,vKillDate,arFilesToKill,true
    next
  end if
end sub 
































'shutdown computer (only if the "yes" shutdown radio button is checked)
'=======================================================================
Sub shutdownsub
    If shutdownverify= "yes" Then
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        'msgbox "shutdown ran!"
        objShell.Run "shutdown.exe -s -t 5"
    Else
        exitscript
    End If
End Sub



'=====================================================
'=====================================================
'=====================================================







'clicking the "settings" button runs this routine
'===================================================
Sub settingsclick
    Msgbox "Default sermon filename is set to:     " & defaultflac & vbnewline & "Storage area for sermon flacs is set to:     " & sermonflacfolder & vbnewline & "Storage location for sermon mp3's set to:   " & sermonmp3folder & vbnewline & "Path to Lame.exe (with flac support) set to:   " & lameexe & vbnewline

End Sub


'clicking the "Examples" button runs this routine
'===================================
Sub examplesclick
    Msgbox "Capitalize the first letter of the sermon title" & vbNewLine & "Capitalize the names of God" & vbNewLine & "For guest speaker, use their name as the title" & vbNewLine & "Here are some examples:"& vbNewLine & vbNewLine &"What hath God wrought"& vbNewLine & "The ABCs of life" & vbNewLine & "Dr Jimmy Stewart"

End Sub


'if no defaultflac file found, exit script
'=========================================
Sub exitscript
    window.close
End Sub






</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that some lines of code "break"?  VBScript has no problem including spaces in string variables: http://jsfiddle.net/74zKp/1/

Comment: When running the hta it will get to the line with the mess of quotes and say things like "expected statement". 

Or with other variations it will launch lame.exe, but lame will break and say it can't find the file "2012_03_23_am_" because it cut off the rest of the line (the part that would have supplied the "sermon title.m3" part).

The errors are many, I can go run it and post the precise errors, but they all stem from my lack of understanding how to make my path variables show up in the lame.exe commnd as if I had typed them in raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths containing spaces in a command line should be enclosed in double quotes.  In VBScript you can double up quotes and they will parse into your string, but this ends up being very hard to read.  I suggest appending the intrinsic constant `vbQuote` or using `Chr(34)` which both return a literal `"`.

```
objShell.Run "cmd.exe /c " & lameexe & " " & Chr(34) & defaultpathfile & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & sermonmp3folder& "\" &newfile& ".mp3" & Chr(34)
```

The crucial parts are:

```
Chr(34) & defaultpathfile & Chr(34)
```

and

```
Chr(34) & sermonmp3folder& "\" &newfile& ".mp3" & Chr(34)
```

Notice how I'm surrounding the file paths with the double quote characters.  This will return strings that include the double quotes.

Your reading has sort of steered you in the wrong direction.  Don't think of this as escaping quotes. You are actually inserting them into your string.

Comment: You're right.  It's been a long day.  I knew something didn't look right.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Unbelievable. It's working.

After analyzing your code... I have my understanding is that:

I can glue together a long string of literals and variables like this..

Comment: Unbelievable. It's working.

After analyzing your code... my understanding is that:

I can glue together a long string of literals and variables like this..

"literal" &var1& "lit2" &var2& "more literals"

But, if my variables are themselves literals, they need doublequoted also (like `"variable"`) but `"variable"` is interpreted as a string.

So using `Chr(34) variable Chr(34)` does the job of doublequoting the variable, without being interpreted as a string.


so & Chr(34) variablewithspacesinitsstring Chr(34)
equals "path with\spaces or other string with spaces"

Is that correct?

Comment: In VBScript, a string is a string of individual characters.  A "string literal" is an explicitly written string value.  VBS, denotes a string literal as a group of characters enclosed by double qoutes like this: `strTest = "I am a string"`.  Because the double quote is a special character in VBScript, you begin to have issues when you want to insert an actual double quote into a string literal.  This breaks your syntax like this: `strTest = "He said, "I am a string""`  VBScript reads from one double quote to the next to parse your literals and you run into the obvious issue...

Comment: ...  The `Chr` function returns a character literal for the ASCII code provided.  So `Chr(34)` returns the ASCII code 34 which is a literal `"`.  We can combine groups of strings, or concatenate them, to build one final string.  That's why this works: `strTest = "He said, " & Chr(34) & "I am a string" & Chr(34)`.  If it's easier to remember, VBScript also provides a built-in constant `vbQuote` for the double quote. `strTest = "He said, " & vbQuote & "I am a string" & vbQuote`

Comment: If this answer has solved your issue, please don't forget to accept it so others can find the solution as well.

Comment: Your fixing the example was very useful, but even more so was your explanation. It's after midnight, so I'll have to revisit this once more to fully grasp it, but your comments have been the most helpful on the entire net. Thanks again!